# Swift Recursively Encode a Custom Class Data Structure

Tags: swift

I want to save a queue in UserDefault. When I decode the Queue from UserDefault, head and tail of the Queue are assigned by value which means they are two completely different objects and I can't enqueue through the tail. Is it possible to encode tail as a reference to head?

This is how class Queue is implemented

```
@State var RecentEmoji = Queue()

public class Node: Codable {
    var value: Int
    var next: Node?
     
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = nil
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case value, next
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        try container.encode(next, forKey: .next)
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        value = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .value)
        next = try container.decode(Node?.self, forKey: .next)
    }
}

public class Queue: Sequence, Codable {
    fileprivate var head: Node?
    private var tail: Node?
    private var length: Int
    
    init() {
        head = nil
        tail = nil
        length = 0
    }

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case head, tail, length
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(head, forKey: .head)
        try container.encode(tail, forKey: .tail)
        try container.encode(length, forKey: .length)
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        head = try container.decode(Node?.self, forKey: .head)
        tail = try container.decode(Node?.self, forKey: .tail)
        length = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .length)
    }
}
```

This is how I save the Queue to userDefault

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let encoded = try encoder.encode(RecentEmoji)
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "RecentEmoji")
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

And this is how I get them back

```
if let savedEmoji = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "RecentEmoji") as? Data {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let recentEmoji = try? decoder.decode(Queue.self, from: savedEmoji) {
        RecentEmoji = recentEmoji
    }
}
```

Comment: By using `try?` you are ignoring any chance to print an error. You may want to use `do/try/catch` and `print(error)` inside the `catch`. Here's a great article on saving a `Codable` type to `UserDefaults`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-load-and-save-a-struct-in-userdefaults-using-codable

Comment: PS -- None of this appears to have to do with SwiftUI -- it's just Swift.

Comment: Edited and fixed the question. Thx